# VBA to deselect items in userform listbox in a certain condition

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using below code to let the user select items from the list while filling up the userform.

However when user select other, I want to **deselect** all items from the same listbox if he has selected any other than the "Other" item.

Below is the code, I am trying, however I don't know how I can deselect *all* items in userform if the User selects "Other" item in the listbox.

```
    For x = 0 To Me.LBX2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.LBX2.Selected(x) Then
            If Me.LBX2.List(x) = "Other" Then
                Me.LBX2.Selected(x) = False      '---This doesn't Deselect the items, not sure why-----
                If myVar1 = "" Then
                    myVar1 = Me.LBX2.List(x, 0)
                Else
                    myVar1 = myVar1 & vbLf & Me.LBX2.List(x, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple selects the Click event is not available and using the Change event requires some logic to avoid an endless loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub ListBox1_change()
    If Not Me.EnableEvents Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim isOther As Boolean, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim var1 As String
    
    With ListBox1
        n = .ListIndex
        If n < 0 Then Exit Sub
        If .List(n) = "Other" Then
            isOther = True
            var1 = .List(n)
        End If

        Me.EnableEvents = False
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If isOther Then
               If i <> n Then .Selected(i) = False
            ElseIf .List(i) = "Other" Then
               .Selected(i) = False
            ElseIf .Selected(i) Then
                If Len(var1) Then var1 = var1 & vbLf
                var1 = var1 & .List(i)
            End If
        Next
        Me.EnableEvents = True
    End With
    MsgBox var1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Unselect Multiselect Listbox items conditionally**

If I understand correctly you have two scenarios:

- an element `Other` has been selected: ~~> unselect all previously selected items other than the selected list element "Other" (memorizing the remaining items though)
- **no** element `Other` has been selected: ~~> memorize all selected items (which of course do not comprise the string `"Other"`)

You might code as follows collecting all selected item(numbers) - *with the exception of `"Other"`* - in array `no`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim elem: ReDim elem(0 To Me.LBX2.ListCount - 1)
    Dim i As Long, nxt As Long: nxt = -1
'a) check element (numbers) of selected items
    For i = 0 To Me.LBX2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.LBX2.Selected(i) Then
            If Me.LBX2.List(i, 0) = "Other" Then
                Dim unselect As Boolean
                unselect = True     ' get status "unselect"
            Else                    ' selected element other than "Other"
                nxt = nxt + 1       ' increment counter
                elem(nxt) = i       ' remember element number
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If nxt > -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve elem(0 To nxt)            ' reduce array length to found items
    Else: Debug.Print "Nothing found to (un)select!": Exit Sub
    End If
'b) remember number & value of selected elements other than "Other"
    If unselect Then
        Debug.Print "A) Unselected: " & vbNewLine & " #";
        For i = 0 To UBound(elem)
            Me.LBX2.Selected(elem(i)) = False   ' << unselect
            elem(i) = elem(i) & " " & Me.LBX2.List(elem(i), 0)
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "B) Selected: " & vbNewLine & " #";
        For i = 0 To UBound(elem)
            elem(i) = elem(i) & " " & Me.LBX2.List(elem(i), 0)
        Next
    End If
'c) display un|selected element (number plus value) in VB Editor's immediate window
    Debug.Print Join(elem, vbNewLine & " #")
End Sub
```

*Just to make the question reproducible with some pseudo data, I add the following initializing procedure:*

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.LBX2
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        .List = Split("a,b,Other,c,d,e", ",")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @T.M. this code also worked for me.